# Save function value to variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this in my AngularJS application:

```
$scope.user = {
    numberValue: null
}
```

and I have this function that returns a value:

```
$scope.formalTrainingCosts = function () {
  return $scope.user.avePaynonTrainedEmployees * $scope.user.newEmployeeFormalTrainingHours;
}
```

Can I save that value to the variable `numberValue` like so `$scope.user.numberValue = $scope.formalTrainingCosts`? If that does not work, what else can I do to get the function saved to the variable?

Comment: `$scope.user.numberValue = $scope.formalTrainingCosts()`.

Comment: @Blackhole - you forgot `;` at the end

Comment: You don't need `;` in JavaScript.

Comment: maybe not always, but it's certainly good practice

Answer (score 0):

the answer by Blackhole will work but you can also put the function straight into the object. The downside to that would be that the function would be called every time you referenced that variable whereas Blackhole's answer would call the function once and save the answer.

```
$scope.user = {
  numberValue: function() {
      return $scope.user.avePaynonTrainedEmployees * $scope.user.newEmployeeFormalTrainingHours;
    }
}
```

or

```
$scope.user = {
  numberValue: $scope.formalTrainingCosts()
}
```